# Method of images for currents?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, method-of-images

[image]

This is a question that uses an “image current configuration”

What exactly is the motivation for using the method of images on a current setup.

The proof I’ve seen for uniqueness theorums was the one in gryffith’s which used the laplace’s equation from gauss’s law so i was of the idea that uniqueness theorums are confined to electrostatics

Is there a more general form that encompasses currents as well?

Additionally what variables make up the boundary conditions in such a new uniqueness theorum?

Comment: The first place in physics where you saw the use of the Laplace's Equation to prove uniqueness theorems is on the voltages. So you know that the voltages might allow you to play with image charges. Now, by Ohm's Law, voltages and currents are but a constant multiple away from each other. I think it is not that far-fetched to try to use image currents.